# bash regex with shopt -s extglob

Tags: regex, bash, validation

I would like to validate input, to be like following:

```
NNN days
NNN hours
NNN minutes
NNN.NNNN seconds
```

, and it has to be negative value, so prefixed with `-`, and plurals being optional.

I have `shopt -s extglob` in my script, and I am using this:

```
while read;do [[ $REPLY =~ ^-[[:digit:]]{1,3}+[[:space:]]{1}(days?|hours?|minutes?|seconds?)$ ]] && echo "GOOD" || echo "BAD"; done
```

How would I implement different rule for seconds, that `NNN.NNNN`?

Also is there a better, cleaner way to specify this regex, from what I am already doing?

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` is only necessary for matching using `?(), !(), ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
^-[[:digit:]]{1,3}(\.[[:digit:]]{1,4})?[[:space:]](days?|hours?|minutes?|seconds?)$
```

You don't need to specify `{1}` for space.

---

If you want decimals **only** for the seconds, then it'll be something uglier (you can replace `\d` with `[[:digit:]]` and `\s` with `[[:space:]]`):

```
^-\d{1,3}((\.?\d{0,4})?\ssecond|\s(day|hour|minute))s?$
```

Thus, the pattern would be (if you want to **ensure** that all seconds values should have decals, change `\.?\d{0,4}` to `\.\d{1,4}` instead):

```
^-[[:digit:]]{1,3}((\.?[[:digit:]]{0,4})?[[:space:]]second|[[:space:]](day|hour|minute))s?$
```

Comment: That will allow for `NNN.NNNN hours` too. I would like decimals to be allowed only with seconds

Comment: Actually your example with `\d` and `\s` substituted does not work for me. But the other one with char classes works fine.